# "Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them" not working with every application with touchpad on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, scrolling

In Windows 10, under *Settings > Devices > Mouse & Touchpad*, I have the "Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them" turned ON.

Using a USB mouse, this setting works as expected - it scrolls the content of whatever application window the mouse is currently hovering over, regardless of whether the window is "active" or "inactive".

When I use my laptop's touchpad, this setting only works when the active window belongs to particular applications (e.g. Firefox, Libre Office Suite). The feature does not work for other applications (e.g. Microsoft OneNote 2016, Sumatra PDF). That is, select the OneNote window, and then hover over the Firefox window, and scrolling on the touchpad will not switch to Firefox, but continue to scroll the OneNote window.

I have spent an hour searching through similar posts on superuser, and while some titles seem like my same issue, once I have read the posts and solutions in detail, they are not the same issue as the problem I am facing. I've also searched more broadly on the Internet without success.

Comment: Any answers? Linux can do this easily, but Windows still can't...

Comment: I haven't found any solutions yet (other than to use a USB mouse, as mentioned in the question)

Comment: Ok, better use linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because inactive scrolling is only designed for a usb mouse, not the trackpad. I have spent months researching this problem. There are some applications that will support inactive scrolling for the trackpad, but not all of them do as you have noticed. However, the good news is that there is a way to fool the computer into thinking your trackpad is a mouse. What you want to do is download "two finger scroll by mac hater". Here is the link: https://github.com/awahlig/two-finger-scroll. Once you install it, you may want to open up your synaptic trackpad settings and "disable" the trackpad (to avoid confusion).

Essentially, "two finger scroll by mac hater" will take over and treat your trackpad as a mouse and you will now be able to scroll inactive windows. Please note that if you restart your computer, you may need to launch the app again in order to scroll. You can simply google how to make programs launch on startup and it is really easy. Your computer will now be able to scroll inactive windows with your trackpad. I have done this and it works like a charm. I hope this helps!

Comment: I am using a k400 keyboard with trackpad and it scrolls windows that are not in focus just fine. (Windows 10 Pro).