# Mousewheel/Touchpad does not scroll but only in the Settings-app on WIndows 10 - otherwise it scrolls fine

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad, scrolling, setup

Actually the title says it all.

I have two new Windows 10 installations on two different Notebooks.
Mouse (Touchpad) works fine, scrolls fine, all is good.
Only in the Settings-app (the cogwheel) in both installations I have to point the mouse pointer  on the right margin for the scroll bar to appear and move the scrollbar by clicking and holding it and moving the mouse.

I cannot figure out why or how to fix this and I am not able to search successfully, because practically every fix regarding Scrolling issues contains "Setup-app", so I don't know how to specify the problem description as pertaining only to the Setup-app.

So any pointers as to a fix or to a successful search would be very much appreciated

Comment: oh man, what a hard thing to search for! Also, quite a strange phenomenon if its only happening in the Settings app. Can you tell us, which touchpad or keyboard with trackpad you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your sympathy!
As I wrote it happens on two different machines, both recently installed with windows 10.  One 21h2 on a Dell E7240 with an ALPS Touchpad, drivers installed - works otherwise fine and as expected and the other a HP Elitebook 8540w with a Syaptics touchpad with 22h2. Also otherwise fine and as expected. 
On both machines/installations the problem was there from the very start.

Comment: So you have two different pieces of hardware, each with their own separate drivers, running on separate systems with the same problem. Most interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into drivers? If not, I'd go to your device brands support page, find your model, and then download any needed drivers. Also look at your device manager in Windows and see if there are any error sings on any devices (shows issues with drivers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, I have, and all is good there. The driver even shows me it is scrolling (A small icon depicting a scrollbar appears next to the tip of the pointer).
Anyway, since this is only happening in Setup-app and all other windows are scrolling fine, I have difficulty imagining that it is a driver issue. It looks like a windows "scroll focus" thing to me.  The nmouse driver is scrolling, but the window does not understand that it is meant itself.

Answer (score 0):

Having said what I said in my reply to IshDeath ( It looks like a windows "scroll focus" thing to me. The nmouse driver is scrolling, but the window does not understand that it is meant itself) I started research on another tangent: scroll focus, scroll inactive windows when I hover over them.
I found that this does not work either (actually it scrolls the active window wherever the pointer is located) and I found this post: ["Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them" not working with every application with touchpad on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1127755/scroll-inactive-windows-when-i-hover-over-them-not-working-with-every-applicat)

Then I went and borrowed a BT mouse to try, and look there, the Settings-app scrolls. So it looks like trackpads aren't too well supported by Windows 10 and there is no real solution.

Comment: I have a Logitech k400 keyboard with a trackpad that works fine in the settings app for scrolling (Windows 10 pro). I would be inclined to the think it was a device issue if it were isolated, but to have two separate devices do the same thing seems odd.